# Filling a 3D pocket with smaller fragments

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array with binary (0 and 1) values representing a voxelized space. A value of 1 means that the voxel is occupied, 0 means it is empty. For simplicity I will describe the problem with 2D data. An example of such a pocket could look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I also have a dataset of fragments which are smaller than the pocket. Think of them as tetris pieces if you'd like, just in 3D. Similar to the game, the fragments can be rotated. Some examples:

```
0 1 1   1 1 1   0 1 1 0
1 1 0   0 0 1   0 1 1 0
```

I am looking to fill in the pocket with the fragments so the remaining empty space (0s) is as small as possible.

So far, I was thinking that I could decompose the pocket into smaller rectangular pockets, calculate the dimensions of these rectangular areas and of the fragments, then just match them based on these dimensions. Or maybe I could rotate the fragments so the values of 1 are closer to the "wall", and focus on boxes closer to the border. Next, I could look up the rectangular areas again and work towards filling in the core/inside of the pocket. To optimize the outcome, I can wrap these steps around a Monte-Carlo Tree Search algo.

Obviously I don't expect a complete answer, but if you have any better ideas on how to approach this, I would be happy to hear it. Any references to similar space search algorithms/papers would also be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the size of your search space and the level of performance you hope to achieve?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a design or research resource.  The packing problem has many algorithms and existing programs on line.  Asking for general leads is out of scope;  asking for off-site resources is out of scope.

Comment: I can control the size of the search space to some degree by setting the voxel size and filtering the number of fragments. Still, I have a large number of fragments (thousands to millions), so an exhaustive approach is not the best. As for performance, I am looking for a balance, but I am inclined to sacrifice some of the precision for speed.

Comment: @Prune, the references were more of a side note. I meant that the problem is quite large and don't expect anyone to implement the complete code for it. I tried to be as specific as I could be about the problem and I am not just looking for a general lead, although I appreciate leads as well.

Comment: Try implementing your approach in 2D, and try to generalize it.